# Ajax XLSX Excel Export

Tags: ajax, excel, export, blob, xlsx

When I do a simple Ajax request like below I get back something like in the image below. Why? When I did CSV export it worked entirely fine, when I do XLSX I get a weird responseText like this.

```
Ajax.request({
            url: '',
            success: function (response) {}
            failure: function () {}
        });
```

[image]

I see there are security measures by browsers blocking Ajax to export itself, so I was using BLOB to export the CSV, same BLOB won't work for XLSX.

More confusing part of this is that, if I create a new XLSX file and right click edit, I see a code that looks like in the picture I attached here too, starts with PK and goes on weird characters...

Comment: CVS worked because it was text XLSX are not text files. Your ajax request will need to return a binary response for you to get it to work.

Comment: It returns a binary response but when I do "request.requestText" inside the browser I get some unknown chars. If I blob without getting the output inside the browser, I get a corrupt file...

Comment: `request.requestText` is text, which is not a binary response. If you're using XMLHTTPRequest, you have to set the responseType to blob or arraybuffer to get a binary response